# Twitter oauth_token and oauth_token_secret only?

Tags: twitter, single-page-application, twitter-oauth

Is it possible to use twitter API having just `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` on client?

I’m getting these tokens via a standard oauth flow on server-side part of my app, but I wonder if I can send requests from the client using just `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`, keeping `oauth_consumer_key` and `oauth_consumer_secret` secure on the server.

The idea is that once I’ve got the tokens, I’ve confimed my identity and should be allowed to use just them(for some time, at least, refreshing them eventually).